# What is the pen that looks similar to a highlighter but is used to clear the writing errors?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

This is a highlighter pen

[image]

> **[highlighter pen](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/highlighter?q=highlighter)**: a special pen used for marking words in a text in bright colours

Now, there is a pen that looks similar to a highlighter but is used to clear the writing errors. To clear the writing errors, you press the pen on the errors & it releases some white sticky liquid, you smear the liquid over the errors, you wait for a few minutes to let the liquid dry. Now you don't see the errors & you can write something on it.

**What is the pen that looks similar to a highlighter but is used to clear the writing errors?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the United States, what you describe is called "[Wite-Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wite-Out)", pronounced as *white-out*. It was invented and trademarked some 50 years ago and comes in different forms. There is Wite-Out tape and Wite-Out pens.

More generally, these things are called correction pens (using correction fluid or white-out) and correction tape.